# error with "Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: missing "=" after "0" in connection"

Tags: php, database, postgresql, connection

sorry i am new to php and postgresql.
im currently trying to connect my database and iv tried two different code (shown below), i'm not sure what else to do.

```php
$dbservername = "localhost";
$dbusername = "username";
$dbpassword = "password";
$dbname = "abattle";


$db = pg_connect("host="+ $dbservername +
    " dbname=" + $dbname +
    " user=" + $dbusername +
    " password=" + $dbpassword)
    or die('connection failed');
               */


$db = pg_pconnect("dbservername=localhost 
    dbusername=username 
    dbpassword=password dbname=abattle") 
    or die('connection failed');
```

so with the commented out code, it gave the error 
Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: missing "=" after "0" in connection

with the code below i get
invalid connection option "dbservername" (same goes for dbusername....)

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string with `pg_pconnect()` is invalid. Use something like

```php
$db = pg_pconnect("host=localhost dbname=abattle user=username password=foo");
```

Check the [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-pconnect.php) for more infos